# Browsers hang whilst trying to resolve my website address

Tags: wordpress, firefox, browser, dns, hosting

hope you can help

I have just moved web hosts and at the same time created a new Wordpress website

I have tried to optimise it as much as possible in terms of loading speed, and it now performs well in tests like GTMetrix (95% rating, about 3 seconds loading time)

However, whenever I visit the site myself (in Firefox) It seems to hang for about 5 seconds before the page even starts to load. At the top of the tab Firefox shows "Connecting..." and in the bottom status bar it shows "waiting for www.domain-name-here.com"

If I try Chrome, the result is the same, although not quite as bad (maybe 2 or 3 seconds of hang before the page loads)

As soon as it "finds" my website it loads lightening fast (a couple of seconds) but its this initial hang of 5 seconds or so which I want to try and get to the bottom of in case others can see it.

It's as if the domain name is difficult to resolve somehow. I do use Cloudflare in a bid to try and speed it up further, but perhaps this could be at fault?

Anything else I can try, or tools I can use to work out where the lag is originating from would be most helpful

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the correct web address in wordpress itself? Go to general settings from the dashboard and check Wordpress Address and Site Address URLs
[image]